# How do you recursively call a constructor (__init__) in Python?

Tags: python, recursion

My question is probably easiest to see in code. I would like to do the following

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
        if i > 0:
            self.a = A(i-1)
```

The idea is that I want to create a class of type A that can recursively call its own constructor. If I code the above and attempt to create an instance of A I get the following:

```
a = Test(3)
--->  self.a = A(i-1)
NameError: global name 'A' is not defined
```

Is it possible to have a class that recursively calls its own constructor? If so, how is it done?

Comment: Your code works ands does not throw an error.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on XP, using python 2.7.1

Comment: Seems you renamed `A` to `Test`, but forgot to rename it everywhere…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to work fine for me when I do `a = A(3)`, why is yours `a = Test(3)`?  I'm guessing that is the issue, if you named your class `Test` then you should use `self.a = Test(i-1)`.

```
>>> class A():
...     def __init__(self, i):
...         self.i = i
...         if i > 0:
...             self.a = A(i-1)
... 
>>> a = A(3)
>>> a.i
3
>>> a.a.i
2
>>> a.a.a.i
1
>>> a.a.a.a.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: A instance has no attribute 'a'
```

Comment: Aha! Turns out I get exactly the same output as you do when I use vanilla python. I was doing this using shell_plus in a django app using iPython. Turns out the error was related to my particular environment, not python itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To recursively call the "constructor" (actually an initializer; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578487/init-as-a-constructor)) you do:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i
        if i > 0:
           self.__init__(i-1)
```

But I suspect that isn't what you're intending to do.  Your example code is recursively creating instances of type `A` and storing them within each other.

Comment: +1 for the "initializer" mention.

Comment: Yeah, my original post wasn't entirely clear. I do actually want to recursively create instances - I'm building something like a tree structure.

Comment: Have you tested this?  I don't think this works.  I tried this with assignment into a `dict`, and it returns `None` instead of a new object.  Works just fine if I use the `ClassName(i-1)` syntax instead.

Comment: @jonathan If you paste exactly the code that I provided, all it does is define a (old style) class with a silly initializer. If you add an instantiation "a = A(10)", then the code does run and a is set to a new instance of A with its "i" member equal to 0.

Comment: @Nathan `self.__init__` cannot be an acceptable solution if it returns `None` when `A(i-1)` returns a value, and, as you're already noted, this solution doesn't *directly* answer the OP's question.  My comment is specifically to counter the "+1 for the "initializer" mention", as it is misplaced in this context.