# Constructor chaining in python

Tags: python, constructor

I have two constructors in my class:

```
def __init__(self):
  self(8)

def __init__(self, size):
  self.buffer = [1] * size
```

Where I want the first constructor to call the second with a default size. Is this achievable in python?

Comment: You don't have two constructors, the second overwrites the first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot define multiple initializers in Python (as pointed in the comments, `__init__` [is not really a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578487/init-as-a-initializer)), but you can define default values, for instance:

```
def __init__(self, size=8):
  self.buffer = [1] * size
```

In the above code, a buffer of size 8 is created by default, but if a size parameter is specified, the parameter will be used instead.

For instance, let's suppose that the initializer is inside a class called `Example`. This call will create a new instance of the class with a buffer of size 8 (the default):

```
e = Example()
```

Whereas this call will create a new instance with a buffer of size 10:

```
e = Example(10)
```

Alternatively, you could also call the constructor like this:

```
e = Example(size=10)
```

Comment: `__init__` is not a constructor, but rather an initializer.  See [`__init__` as a constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578487/init-as-a-constructor).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @Nathan. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot overload methods in Python. In this case, you could just use a default value for the `size` parameter instead:

```
def __init__(self, size=8):
  self.buffer = [1] * size
```

Answer (score 1):

probably not in this way. Python classes use an internal dictionary to store its method and properties, a second method with same name overrides the first one.
You could assign a default value to your extra parameter to do this,

```
def __init__(self, size = 8):
  self.buffer = [1] * size
```

Answer (score 0):

What you suggest is possible in languages that allow constructor overloading. This is not possible in python. For simple cases, the suggested default parameter is the best way ( `__init__(self,size=8)`). If you need more complex alternative constructors (imagine reading and parsing parameters from a string or so), you would use classmethods in python:

```
class thingWithBuffer:
    def __init__(self, buffer_size):
        self.buffer = buffersize
    
    @classmethod
        def create_with_default_buffer(cls):
            return cls(buffer_size=8)
```

[pynative has a nice overview of how to use classmethods](https://pynative.com/python-class-method/)