# Ensuring __init__ is only called once when class instance is created by constructor or __new__

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand how new instances of a Python class should be created when the creation process can either be via the constructor or via the `__new__` method. In particular, I notice that when using the constructor, the `__init__` method will be automatically called after `__new__`, while when invoking `__new__` directly the `__init__` class will not automatically be called. I can force `__init__` to be called when `__new__` is explicitly called by embedding a call to `__init__` within `__new__`, but then `__init__` will end up getting called twice when the class is created via the constructor.

For example, consider the following toy class, which stores one internal property, namely a `list` object called `data`: it is useful to think of this as the start of a vector class.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return obj

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.__new__(type(self), self.data[index])

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.data)
```

A new instance of the class can be created either using the constructor (not actually sure if that is the right terminology in Python), something like

`x = MyClass(range(10))`

or via slicing, which you can see invokes a call to `__new__` in the `__getitem__` method.

`x2 = x[0:2]`

In the first instance, `__init__` will be called twice (both via the explicit call within `__new__` and then again automatically), and once in the second instance. Obviously I would only like `__init__` to be invoked once in any case. Is there a standard way to do this in Python?

Note that in my example I could get rid of the `__new__` method and redefine `__getitem__` as

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    return MyClass(self.data[index])
```

but then this would cause a problem if I later want to inherit from `MyClass`, because if I make a call like `child_instance[0:2]` I will get back an instance of `MyClass`, not the child class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, some basic facts about `__new__` and `__init__`:

- `__new__` is a **constructor**.
- `__new__` typically returns an instance of `cls`, its first argument.
- By `__new__` returning an instance of `cls`, [`__new__` causes Python to call `__init__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__).
- `__init__` is an **initializer**. It modifies the instance (`self`)
  returned by `__new__`. It does not need to return `self`.

When `MyClass` defines:

```
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return obj
```

`MyClass.__init__` gets called twice. Once from calling `obj.__init__` explicitly, and a second time because `__new__` returned `obj`, an instance of `cls`. (Since the first argument to `object.__new__` is `cls`, the instance returned is an instance of `MyClass` so `obj.__init__` calls `MyClass.__init__`, not `object.__init__`.)

---

The [Python 2.2.3 release notes](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/#__new__) has an interesting comment, which sheds light on when to use `__new__` and when to use `__init__`:

> The `__new__` method is called with the class as its first argument; its
>   responsibility is to return a new instance of that class.
>
> Compare this to `__init__`:`__init__` is called with an instance as its
>   first argument, and it doesn't return anything; its responsibility is
>   to initialize the instance.
>
> All this is done so that immutable types can preserve their
>   immutability while allowing subclassing.
>
> The immutable types (int, long, float, complex, str, unicode, and
>   tuple) have a dummy `__init__`, while the mutable types (dict, list,
>   file, and also super, classmethod, staticmethod, and property) have a
>   dummy `__new__`.

So, use `__new__` to define immutable types, and use `__init__` to define mutable types. While it is possible to define both, you should not need to do so.

---

Thus, since MyClass is mutable, you should only define `__init__`:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return type(self)(self.data[index])

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.data)

x = MyClass(range(10))
x2 = x[0:2]
```

Comment: This is misleading. First, `__new__` doesn't call `__init__` then return the instance. `__new__` is called to create an instance,  then `__init__` is invoked on what `__new__` returned. This is why invoking `__new__` directly doesn't call `__init__`. Second, `__new__` is nothing like a constructor, and should not be called one. `__init__` is called a constructor in the official Python docs.

Comment: @Ben, do you have a reference from the python docs?  It seems that would clear up a lot of debate on whether `__init__` is a constructor ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578487/init-as-a-constructor

Comment: @pylang The docs for Python 2.6 have a note "As a special constraint on constructors, no value may be returned" in the description for `__init__` (https://docs.python.org/2.6/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization). Later versions of the docs have reworded the sentence. None that I'm aware of have ever called `__new__` the constructor. Note that Python only had `__init__` for many versions, as a direct port of the concept of constructors from other OO languages; `__new__` was a later addition. I don't think anyone ever felt the need to deny that `__init__` was a constructor back then.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that shouldn't be done:

- Call `__init__` from `__new__`
- Call `__new__` directly in a method

As you have already seen, both the `__new__` and the `__init__` methods are automatically called when creating an object of a given class. Using them directly would break this functionality (calling `__init__` inside another `__init__` is allowed though, as it can be seen in the example below).

You can get the class of the object in any method getting the `__class__` attribute as in the following example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # Customized __new__ implementation here
        return obj

    def __init__(self, data):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(self)
        self.data = data

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        cls = self.__class__
        return cls(self.data[index])

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.data)

x = MyClass(range(10))
x2 = x[0:2]
```

Comment: What then is the purpose of the `__new__()` in the class as shown in your example?

Comment: @martineau Thanks for your comment. The `__new__` implementation in the example was there just as a placeholder for any desired implementation. Anyway, as pointed out by @unutbu in his response, it's true that is not really needed for this particular question, so I've updated my response to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an instance of a class with `MyClass(args)`, the default instance creation sequence is as follows:

1. `new_instance  = MyClass.__new__(args)` is invoked to get a new "blank" instance
2. `new_instance.__init__(args)` is invoked (`new_instance` is the instance returned from the call to `__new__` as above) to initialise the attributes of the new instance [1]
3. `new_instance` is returned as the result of `MyClass(args)`

From this, it is clear to see that calling `MyClass.__new__` yourself will **not** result in `__init__` being called, so you'll end up with an uninitialised instance. It's equally clear that putting a call to `__init__` into `__new__` will also not be correct, as then `MyClass(args)` will call `__init__` *twice*.

The source of your problem is this:

> I'm trying to understand how new instances of a Python class should be
> created when the creation process can either be via the constructor or
> via the **new** method

The creation process should not normally be via the `__new__` method at all. `__new__` is a *part* of the normal instance creation protocol, so you shouldn't expect it to invoke the whole protocol for you.

One (bad) solution would be to implement this protocol by hand yourself; instead of:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    return self.__new__(type(self), self.data[index])
```

you could have:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    new_item = self.__new__(type(self), self.data[index])
    new_item.__init__(self.data[index])
    return new_item
```

But really, what you want to do is not mess with `__new__` at all. The default `__new__` is fine for your case, and the default instance creation protocol is fine for you case, so you should neither implement `__new__` nor call it directly.

What you want is to create a new instance of the class the normal way, by calling the class. If there's no inheritance going on and you don't think there ever will be, simply replace `self.__new__(type(self), self.data[index])` with `MyClass(self.data[index])`.

If you think there might one day be subclasses of `MyClass` that would want to create instances of the subclass through slicing rather than `MyClass`, then you need to dynamically get the class of `self` and invoke that. You already know how to do this, because you used it in your program! `type(self)` will return the type (class) of `self`, which you then can invoke exactly as you would invoke it directly through `MyClass`: `type(self)(self.data[index])`.

---

As an aside, the point of `__new__` is when you want to customise the process of getting a "new" blank instance of a class before it is initialised. Almost all of the time, this is completely unnecessary and the default `__new__` is fine.

You only need `__new__` in two circumstances:

1. You're have an unusual "allocation" scheme, where you might return an existing instance rather than create a genuinely new one (the only way to actually create a new instance is to delegate to the ultimate default implementation of `__new__` anyway).
2. You're implementing a subclass of an immutable builtin type. Since the immutable builtin types can't be modified after creation (because they're immutable), they must be initialised **as** they're created rather than afterwards in `__init__`.

As a generalisation of point (1), you can make `__new__` return whatever you like (not necessarily an instance of the class) to make invoking a class behave in some arbitrarily bizarre manner. This seems like it would almost always be more confusing than helpful, though.

---

[1] I believe in fact the protocol is slightly more complex; `__init__` is only invoked on the value returned by `__new__` if it's an instance of the class that was invoked to start the process. However it's very unusual for this not to be the case.