# The true purpose of init when it comes to class inheritance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor, init

As the title suggests, I am struggling to understand the true purpose of the init constructor in Python and specifically when we create a class that inherits from another (parent). Having gone through "diveintopython", I am a bit confused as to what exactly happens when class B inherits from A.

In the following example (taken from here: [What is the purpose of calling __init__ directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126734/what-is-the-purpose-of-calling-init-directly))

```
class A:

 def __init__(self, x):
      self.x = x

class B(A):

 def __init__(self, x, y):
      A.__init__(self, x)
      self.y = y
```

What exactly happens if we don't make the call to the parent init `A.__init__(self, x)`?

Will attribute x still exist in class B?

Furthermore, shouldn't `Class B(A)` already entail the call to parent init?
In other words are we allowed to skip the call, and if we do which would be the consequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `__init__` is called only after the object is created in memory, unlike C++. So, its true purpose is to initialize/create instance variables only.
2. If you don't call the parent's `__init__`, it will not create the variable `x`. See, what we are passing as the first parameter to the parent's `__init__` call. We pass the current object (`self`). Now, the parent's `__init__`, creates the variable `x` on the child's object.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't make the call to `__init__`, then no, `x` will not exist on that instance of class `B`. `A.__init__` will not be run because you never called it!

`class B(A)` means that `B` inherits from `A`, but it doesn't automagically call the constructor of `A` when you make an instance of `B`. This means that you can control whether you want it yourself - you generally should be calling the constructor, but it's your choice whether you want to or not. The consequences depend on the class you're subclassing - there may be no problems, or your code may not work at all. In this case, as I've said, if you skip the call to `A.__init__` and then try

```
b = B()
print(b.x)
```

you'll get an exception.

Just as a general note, you don't have to name the superclass when calling its `__init__` - you can use `super(B, self).__init__(x)` or just `super().__init__(x)` in Python 3.

Comment: So if I skip the call to init (and thus live without attribute x), do I still get to inherit class A methods (even if they end up broken)?

Comment: @Konos5 yes, the methods will still be there, but possibly broken.